# PHP Current time in Hour:Minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I want to have have 2 variables with the current time in hours:minutes and also one that has +15 minutes. But first I must also add +6 hours.

So for example, right now it is `2018-01-07 16:35:10`. So first I add +6 hours. So it will be `2018-01-07 22:35:10`. Next, I want to extract only the hours:minutes.

I want to get only "22:35" to variable.

And next variable, I want 22:35 +15 minutes, so 22:50.

So I have `$dateNow = 22:35` and `$dateThen = 22:50`

I have tried this so far to get current time now and +6 hours, but it's not working. Error: `Call to a member function format() on integer`

```
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +6 hours");
$then = $now->format('H:i');
echo $then;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think in this case it would be very use full to use the DateTime class from PHP. The Problem with your code is [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a int not an DateTime object.

I've modified your code so it will work:

```
$org = new DateTime("2018-01-07 16:35:10");
$then = $org->add(new DateInterval("PT6H"));
echo $then->format("H:i"),"<br>";
$afterThen = $then->add(new DateInterval("PT15M"));
echo $afterThen->format("H:i");
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! `$a = new DateTime("+360 minutes");
$now = $a->format('H:i');
echo $now . '<br><br>';

$b = new DateTime("+375 minutes");
$then = $b->format('H:i');
echo $then;`

Answer (score 1):

Short solution with `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$result = $now->add(new DateInterval('PT6H15M'))->format('H:i');
```

Comment: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string i

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$time = time() + 3600 * 6; // add 6 hours
$date = date("H:i", $time); // format date
$date_plus_15 = date("H:i", $time + 60 * 15); // format date and add 15 minutes

echo "Time: {$date} <br>";
echo "Time + 15 mins: {$date_plus_15}";
```

Example here: https://ideone.com/ZR6cfy